# Agilent Gen5 files

Tags: encodings

Does anyone know how to decode these agilent gen5 files for detection (xpt), or know of a tool/script that can extract the information? They have some example files on their website.

https://www.agilent.com/en/product/microplate-instrumentation/microplate-instrumentation-control-analysis-software/imager-reader-control-analysis-software/gen5-lhc-sample-files